# Scrollview children are not clickable when Scrollview position is absolute

Tags: css, react-native, scrollview

I have a Scrollview with position: absolute, and its children are not clickable. Click goes just right through them and on a component below. I tried to google this issue. A lot of people ask, but there are not many solutions. One of solutions I found is to set the height of a scrollview, which is set. Also, I added elevation with no effect. Other than that, I couldn't find anything.

It happens on Android, but I can't test it on iOS right now.

```
export const Component: FC = ({}) => {
    const popUpRender = () => {
        return [
            durations.map(duration => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        key={duration}
                        onPress={() => {
                            console.log('clicked')
                        }}>
                        <Text>text</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            }),
        ]
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={[styles.popUp]}>{popUpRender()}</ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        zIndex: 11,
    },
    popUp: {
        position: 'absolute',
        elevation: 5,
        zIndex: 100,
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
})
```

I have to have scrollview positioned absolute. Is there a way make its children clickable?

Answer (score 0):

can I just ask you why do you have to have the scrollview as absolutt position?

Comment: It's a custom dropdown list. When it's open, it has to float above everything else. Also, the issue persists with a regular View as well.

Comment: Just to explain it better. I made a dropdown list with clickable items. So it's a Scrollview with absolute position when dropdown is open. Just so it floats above other elements. Inside of it, there is a list of TouchableOpacity items. But they are not clickable. Is there a way to achieve the same thing without position absolute?

Comment: have you tried wrapping the scrolview with a normal view which is positioned absolut?

Comment: Sure. The issue persists. It looks like any component inside any component with position absolute isn't clickable.